# Increment operators and "undefined behaviour"

Tags: c, language-lawyer

As mentioned in the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/expr/seqpoints.html), the C standard states:

> Between the previous and next sequence point an object shall have its
>   stored value modified at most once by the evaluation of an expression.
>   Furthermore, the prior value shall be accessed only to determine the
>   value to be stored.

But, this [(now deleted) article](https://web.archive.org/web/20160815164535/http://www.ganssle.com/rants/sequencepoints.htm) says that `a = ++b + ++c;` is undefined. Could someone please explain why this is undefined behaviour?

Comment: I think Mr Ganssle is wrong in this instance.

Comment: One way to make it UB: `#define b a`

Comment: That looks like an error in the article.

Comment: Note that `a = ++b+++c;` would indeed be incorrect, but a constraint violation rather than undefined behavior.

Comment: I don't know why that would be undefined. It's clear that the value of `++b` is `b + 1`. Something like `a = ++b + ++b` is another story.

Comment: Thanks all, for a moment I felt like starting with K&R again. Thanks for pointing that out @EOF

Comment: This *has* to be a duplicate...

Comment: This is not the support forum of that site. Why not ask the author to explain in detail. Note: he is plain wrong. Before starting a rant about something, one really should have understood it. And regarding the rest of that article: It has the same quality like rainbow press. That person apparently has not understood the idea of short-circuit evaluation either (which is not a C-special, but exists in most (imperative) languages, btw.). I'd recommend to follow some other site like stack overflow ;-) instead.

Comment: If this is UB not at least also depends on the types and values of those three variables. We don't want no signed integer overflow.

Comment: I feel like 3 people just went "oh hell not this question again".

Comment: Based on reading that article, it sounds like Ganssle is confusing the *result* of the `++` operator with its *side effect*.  The *result* of `++b` is the current value of `b` plus 1, so `a` is getting the value of `b+1 + c+1`, using the *current* values of `b` and `c` (i.e., before the side effect has been applied).  As others have pointed out, the behavior is well defined as long as `a`, `b`, and `c` are distinct objects.

Comment: @babon So you have the honor to point the author at this bug.

Comment: @StoryTeller: It's not the usual question (why isn't a++ + a++ giving me the answer I expect); it's something far rarer (why is someone claiming well-defined behavior is undefined).

Comment: another one of the many errors on that page: he claims `i = ++i;` is unspecified, when in fact it is undefined (in C99)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Provided the objects involved (`a`, `b` and `c`) in the expression `a = ++b + ++c;` are distinct, that expression is well-defined.

Perhaps, the author meant to use the same variable twice such as `a = ++b + ++b;`. I can only speculate. But there's no undefinedness in the given expression.

Comment: `int b  = INT_MAX, c = INT_MAX; int a = ++b + ++c;`?

Comment: @alk that would be stretching it, wouldn't it ?

Comment: @alk - Ganssle apparently believes (wrongly) that the expression is undefined because of the use of the `++` operator specifically.

Comment: moral of the story: don't trust random internet pages about C.  trust the standard drafts, and (mostly) upvoted stackoverflow answers

Comment: @M.M SO is reliable if the topic is well known. Obscure ones, even highly upvoted, can be just as wrong and must be verified from multiple sources.